# How can I retrain existing spacy v3 NER model with additional data?

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, spacy

I have trained Spacy v3 model on 1 million rows and want to train for additional 1 million.

```
!python -m spacy train spacy_v3/config.cfg --output spacy_v3/output --paths.train spacy_v3/train.spacy --paths.dev spacy_v3/test.spacy --gpu-id 0
```

While training on additional 1 million or more data, I want to start my training from the previous best-model. Is there anyway to retrain existing ner model?

Comment: Did you find a solution?